# SVG filter to create waves from straight lines

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am try to reply the effect in the picture with SVG. Do you have any hint on how I can obtain that (other than manually drawing the paths?).

Basically I was thinking to draw or create a pattern of vertically straight lines and then apply an effect on them. The result doesn't have to be 100% equal to the one provided, but similar.

[image: svg pattern]

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms so you'd have to draw it manually.

Comment: I am trying using feDisplaceMap with a gradient or a hand drawn pattern

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do without drawing the lines specifically is to distort them using a feDisplacementMap filter - but the results aren't even close to what you're hoping for because filters work in bitmaps.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">

<defs>
<pattern id="diagonal" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
  <path d="M0 0 l 10 10" 
        stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
</pattern>
  
  <filter id="distort">
    <feTurbulence baseFrequency = "0.015" type="fractalNoise" />
    <feDisplacementMap in='SourceGraphic' xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="60"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA  type="table" tableValues="0 .1 .5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1"/>
                          <feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</defs>

  <g filter="url(#distort)">
<rect x="10" y="10" width="300" height="300" fill="url(#diagonal)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: what does it means and implies, that filter works in bitmap?

Comment: filters convert SVG vector drawnigs to pixels before they operate on them.